# CakePHP: Cant delete in beforeSave method

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am having a problem with deleting data from a table in a plugin.

In the Model I am calling:

```
$this->delete((int) $this->data['Attachment']['id']);
```

But it is not deleting, and the ID is correct.

Comment: Could you provide more context? Is this from within the Attachment model?

Comment: What's `$this`? What is the full beforeSave callback? does calling delete execute a query? what is the return value?

Comment: Are you sure beforeSave is triggered? for example in saveAll beforeSave doesn't triggers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25670891/cant-delete-row-from-beforesave-method-in-cakephp-2-4

This answer actually helps me. It's a same question.

Answer (score 0):

Please test :

```
$this->Model->delete($this->request->data('Model.id'));
```